# Problem with Oracle BI Answers Calendar Prompt

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence

I have a calendar prompt which when selected is in the format 'MM/DD/YYYY' but when the filter is applied the timestamp gets appended to it.

Please see the attached picture.

I do not want the timestamp to be appended after applying the filter.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem - The data type of the selected column was DATETIME in the physical layer. Once I changed it to DATE everything was fine